# How to use a common anode 7-segment, 4-digit display?

Tags: led, display, rgb-led, multiplexer, 7-segment

Please take this question as an example to (my own) answer below.

I've got an 7 segment, 4 digit LED display, but I don't have any idea on how to wire it.

I don't understand the difference between common anode/cathode, and I don't have 2 pins per LED, which is strange. 
Quite recently, a question on a "7 segment 4 digit common anode" got deleted. 
At that very moment I was typing an answer.

Though, I still want to share my answer with you, or the person who asked it.
Please verify/update my answer with more information. 
Specifically, could someone add working code, I can't at the moment.

Comment: Just curious. Did you post a question so you can answer it?

Comment: There is actually an option for that. However, the comments in my question also tell the "background story". I was answering a question, that got deleted. And felt a need to post my answer neverthless. So yes, I did. But it's a valid method and I had the answer before the question. So it made sense to me. If you've got a really good question (and answer), I could only encourage you to do the same, as it might come usefull to someone at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as a complement to Paul's answer, I wrote a short program to show
how to drive the 7-segment 4-digit display of his figure:

[image: wiring schematic]

This is actually a common cathode display, so the program assumes that,
as well as the particular wiring of the figure. The interesting part is
the `refresh_display()` function, which should be called periodically.
The algorithm is as follows:

- drive the 7 anodes with the appropriate signals for one of the digits
  we want to show
- set `HIGH` the output that controls that digit's cathode through the
  NPN transistor
- wait for 2.5 ms (for a refresh rate of 100 Hz)
- set `LOW` the cathode-controlling output
- move to the next digit.

It should be noted that the waiting is done without blocking the CPU, by
using the technique described in the [Blink Without
Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) Arduino
tutorial. Here is the program:

```c++
const int NB_DIGITS     = 4;  // 4-digit display
const int FIRST_ANODE   = 2;  // anodes a..g on pins 2..8
const int FIRST_CATHODE = 9;  // cathodes, right to left, on pins 9..12

// Digits to display, from right to left.
uint8_t digits[NB_DIGITS];

// Set all the used pins as outputs.
void init_display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        pinMode(FIRST_ANODE + i, OUTPUT);
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_DIGITS; i++)
        pinMode(FIRST_CATHODE + i, OUTPUT);
}

// This should be called periodically.
void refresh_display()
{
    // Our 7-segment "font".
    static const uint8_t font[10] = {
        //abcdefg
        0b1111110, // 0
        0b0110000, // 1
        0b1101101, // 2
        0b1111001, // 3
        0b0110011, // 4
        0b1011011, // 5
        0b1011111, // 6
        0b1110000, // 7
        0b1111111, // 8
        0b1111011  // 9
    };

    // Wait for 2.5 ms before switching digits.
    static uint32_t last_switch;
    uint32_t now = micros();
    if (now - last_switch < 2500) return;
    last_switch = now;

    // Switch off the current digit.
    static uint8_t pos;
    digitalWrite(FIRST_CATHODE + pos, LOW);

    // Set the anodes for the next digit.
    pos = (pos + 1) % NB_DIGITS;
    uint8_t glyph = font[digits[pos]];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        digitalWrite(FIRST_ANODE + i, glyph & 1 << (6-i));

    // Switch digit on.
    digitalWrite(FIRST_CATHODE + pos, HIGH);
}

/***********************************************************************
 * Example usage.
 */

void setup()
{
    init_display();
}

void loop()
{
    uint32_t now = millis();

    // Change the number displayed every second.
    static uint32_t last_change;
    if (now - last_change >= 1000) {
        digits[3] = digits[2];
        digits[2] = digits[1];
        digits[1] = digits[0];
        digits[0] = (digits[0] + 1) % 10;
        last_change = now;
    }

    refresh_display();
}
```

Paul provided a link to a [tutorial on
Parallax](http://learn.parallax.com/4-digit-7-segment-led-display-arduino-demo)
that suggests using the
[Multiplex7Seg](https://github.com/jhartshorn/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/Multiplex7Seg)
Arduino library. That library is more general than the example code
above, as it does not make assumptions about the pins used. But the big
difference between the library and this code is in the way the timings
are managed:

- The library is driven by the Timer 2 overflow interrupt. This should
  provide a very steady timing, at the cost of having one timer
  dedicated to this job.
- The code above relies on the user calling `refresh_display()` often
  enough. It doesn't require dedicated hardware resources, but it
  doesn't play well with programs that take too long to `loop()`: it
  won't like you calling `delay()`.

Comment: This is why I like open-source stuff. You can share workload with the rest of the world and create something really nice. Which is then shared with the rest of the world again :) You can learn a lot from other developers and that knowledge will be persistent and not just hidden from everyone else.

Comment: I have a question in mind regarding Tranistor's base resistor value. I've a great problem with calculating resistor value. What is the reason for using 4.7K resistor in four 2N2222 transistor? If a single segment consume 10mA then there will be maximum 80mA current drawing for all segment including DP. If V(BE *sat) = 1.3v and I(B) = 15mA then 300ohm will be enough. Is there any wrong with my calculation?

Comment: @maruf: The _minimum_ required I\_B is the expected I\_C divided by the minimum transistor gain. If you want 80 mA on the collector and expect a gain of at least 100 (it may be optimistic, I did not check the datasheet), then you need at least 80/100 = 0.8 mA on the base. Then the _maximum_ value of the base resistor is the voltage drop across it (about 5 V − 0.7 V) divided by that current, or about 5.3 kΩ.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try and take you through the complete basics of LED's etc.
As 4-digit 7-segment displays are a combination of multiple "LED techniques".

**Wiring LED's**

LED's, or Light Emitting Diodes, are one of the fun things of Arduino.

Essentially, they're easy to use, power them up and they'll light up.

They can be annoying, because they have some kind of polarity, meaning that they will only work when you wire them right. If you reverse positive and negative voltage, they won't light up at all.

Annoying as it is, it's also quite usefull.

**Cathode vs Anode**

On a traditional LED, the long lead is the (+), Anode.
The other lead being the (-) Cathode.

"Or, if someone’s trimmed the legs, try finding the flat edge on the LED’s outer casing. The pin nearest the flat edge will be the negative, cathode pin." - Sparkfun

Source: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/polarity/diode-and-led-polarity

[image: Sparkfun]

**Basic wiring**

I'm not sure if this is correct, since I ripped the image from the internet.

[image: Basic LED wiring]

Wiring an LED is quite easy, the Anode (+) connects to positive voltage, preferably through a current limiting resistor.
The Cathode (-) connects to ground (with a current limiting resistor, if you didn't have one on the positive side).

The current limiting resistor will avoid the LED from shorting out, damaging the LED or Microcontroller/Arduino.

**Multiple LEDs, matrices, RGB leds**

With multiple LED's you often have them with the positive side connected (+), "common Anode" or all connected to the (-) "common Cathode".

Basically it'll come down to this.

[image: RGB common cathode/anode]

For a common cathode, you supply current to the pins that you want to have on.

For a common anode, you sink the current through the LED.

**Multiplexing (multiple digit, 7-segments)**

You should check out the tutorial of parallax: http://learn.parallax.com/4-digit-7-segment-led-display-arduino-demo

[image: Parallax 4digit7seg]

When you've got a lot of LED's, it's often smart to "multiplex" them. Usually you go through "groups" of LED's rapidly, so that it looks like they're all on at the same time.

Usually you sink current from a column of LED's and supply current to individual LED's of a row.

Or, you supply current to a column of LED's and sink current from individual LED's of a row.

So that you can choose which column to activate, and which LED's of that column to light up. Changing these columns/rows rapidly will enable you to control multiple LED's with a lot less pins.

There even are display controllers for this, if you don't want to take care of the switching in your software.

**So when you have a 4 digit, multiplexed 7 segment, common anode**

The diagram will be more like this:

[image]

http://www.mytutorialcafe.com/Microcontroller%20Application%20C%207segmen.htm